# Filter object data by value

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given the following Data

```
{ player1: 'healthy',
  player4: 'ready',
  player2: 'uncertain',
  player3: 'uncertain' 
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way in **lodash** to filter object by it's value. For instance I want to get a list/array that only has players with uncertain status and i would want another list that has all the players that do not have uncertain status.

Possible Solution

This is something I think could work but not sure if it is correct or the right way to do it.

```
const result = _.pickBy(data, (key, value) => value.startsWith("uncert"));
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use lodash and not JS's native filter function?

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt working in a codebase that is mostly lodash so trying to stay consistent

Comment: _.filter(data, {name: 'uncertain'});

Comment: @AmirAfghani does not seem to work

Comment: You forgot to use _.startsWith(value, "uncert"), take a look in my answer, i hope its help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const data  = { 
  player1: 'healthy',
  player4: 'ready',
  player2: 'uncertain',
  player3: 'uncertain' 
}

result = _.pickBy(data, (value) => _.startsWith(value, "uncert"));
```

Comment: This works, now how do i get  a lit of all values that are not uncertain. can i use_.difference ?

Comment: I don't know if i undesrtanded what do you whant, but you can can just deny the expression like this:                                                                                   result = _.pickBy(data, (value) => !_.startsWith(value, "uncert"));

Answer (score 1):

Get an array keys with `_.keys()`, and then use `_.partition()` to get an arrays of `uncertain` / `certain` by checking if the original value from the object is `uncertain` (or starts with/includes/etc...):

```js
const data = {player1: 'healthy',player4: 'ready',player2: 'uncertain',player3: 'uncertain'}

const value = 'uncertain'

const [uncertain, certain] = _.partition(_.keys(data), key => data[key] === value)

console.log(uncertain)
console.log(certain)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: I posted another Q that you may be able to help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082844/refactoring-when-two-functions-share-some-similarity

Answer (score 0):

i don't sure if i understand well, but should be without lodash:

```js
const data = {
  player1: 'healthy',
  player4: 'ready',
  player2: 'uncertain',
  player3: 'uncertain'
}

const prefix = 'uncert'

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce(
  (lists, player) => (lists[!Number(data[player].includes(prefix)) % 2].push(player), lists),
  [[], []]
)

console.log('players with ' + prefix, result[0])
console.log('players without ' + prefix, result[1])
```